# How to create csv file on heroku server directory?

Tags: javascript, php, csv, heroku, server

i have some form fields like input type (text,email,phone no, email, checkbox) and a submit button. I want to when i click on submit button it shows thank you message to user and create a new csv file on server including form fields data if there is no csv and if there is already csv having some data it should be append new row in csv. If is it possible please help me out i'm new on php. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add some code that you have written so far.

Comment: Hi @ssuperczynski can you share some link related to same . Actually i have no idea how to do. Your help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can't! Heroku doesn't let you modify the server once its deployed. This is called immutable servers it became common pattern for cloud platforms.

Think about it, what happens when you run multiple nodes of the same app, which one will hold the files? what happens when you deploy a new version of your application (heroku replaces the machines underneath) so files will be lost.

To persist data applications on heroku use data stores, for example amazon S3 lets you store arbitrary files on their elastic storage.
There are heroku addons to help you integrate with such services (for example this [one](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer)), but that's not mandatory, you can integrate directly.

Of course there are other hacks like storing file contents in a DB (heroku offers free postgresql with a few MBs of storage) but that's not [recommended](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) regardless of the cloud vendor.
In your specific case it sounds like the best solution is to model the text, email, phone etc.. into database columns, so every "file" is a row in the DB.